# meaning of "exercise care"

Tags: meaning

[From a tutorial](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/under-below-beneath-and-underneath/4785334.html)

> “below” and “beneath” can refer to people or things that are unworthy in some way or of a lower social ranking.
>
> ...
>
> Some people think she married below her family.
>
> This meaning is negative, however. So **exercise care** when using it.

Does "exercise care" means here "be careful"? Is it an idiom? I looked it up in some dictionaries but didn't find an item/entry for it.

Should I go with these meanings in the Cambridge Dictionary and put them together?

> [exercise](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exercise): to do physical activities to make your body strong and healthy

> [care](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/care): the process of protecting someone or something and providing what that person or thing needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an idiom, but the definitions you provided are incorrect. It does appear to be a bit difficult to find the appropriate definitions that fit this fairly common phrase. Here are the best I could find.

[From Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/exercise_2):

> **Exercise** (TRANSITIVE VERB)
> to use a skill or personal quality, especially in order to avoid problems
> *Caution must be exercised when operating this equipment.*

> **Care** (UNCOUNTABLE NOUN)
> effort and attention
> *I can see that a lot of care has gone into your work.*

So if I use these definitions together, it would be:

To *exercise care* means to **use effort and attention to avoid problems*.

But it can be simplified:

To *exercise care* means to **use caution**. So your understanding of **be careful** is correct.